# Intellij Idea. How to make custom scope pattern for hiding class files but show library folder?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, scopes, custom-scope

Im writing software for external program and launching it. This program generates class files in project folder for each java file (its just compiles it and doing some work, that idea cannot do for some reasons).
I have around 60 classes at the moment and its hard to view all my source code files.
So i found solution - idea scopes. i got scope and hide an unused files but pattern isnt clear for me. My pattern ignores lib folders.

My pattern so far:  `lib:*..*||!file:*.class`

And it hiding library folder.
Is there way to show library folder but hide all specific files on project code?

Comment: How did you configure the lib folder in the IDE module settings? Is it excluded, is it under any content root? Does it belong to any library added to the module dependencies. A sample module layout would help to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: lib added with ctrl + shift + s menu and its folder with packages and .class files.

Comment: Library and output folders cannot be shown in scopes.

Comment: Thats dumb... Thanks.